# Правильно ли составлено предложение?

Tags: грамматика, спп, редактура

Кажется, мы стали забывать, кто из исторических рэп-фигур в одиночку с пеной у рта проложил дорогу в русскую хип-хоп индустрию, кто агрессивным натиском и безудержным напором вырвался из мейнстрима, кто стал путеводной звездой и источником вдохновения для сотен тысяч людей по всему миру, а также того, кто в своих изысканных, умных и проникновенных треках отчетливо напомнил об эпохе самовыражения.

Comment: Напишите правильный вариант построения предложения. Чтобы не было ни стилистических ошибок, ни грамматических.
Спасибо!

Comment: "Кажется, мы стали забывать, кто... , кто... , кто... , (; стали) забывать того, кто... ." Стилистически не совсем удачно использование выражения "с пеной у рта" (это негативное выражение - при общем позитивном смысле).

Comment: "Кажется, мы стали забывать, кто из исторических рэп-фигур в одиночку проложил дорогу в русскую хип-хоп индустрию, кто агрессивным натиском и безудержным напором вырвался из мейнстрима, кто стал путеводной звездой и источником вдохновения для сотен тысяч людей по всему миру;  забывать того,  кто в своих изысканных, умных и проникновенных треках отчетливо напомнил об эпохе самовыражения". 

Верно?

Comment: Да, но лучше обойтись простой запятой (при точке с запятой я бы воспроизвёл и второй глагол, чтобы не разрывать их связь).

Answer (score 2):

По-видимому,  явно имеющийся здесь диссонанс возникает из-за использования глагола "забывать" сначала в качестве **непереходного** (*забывать [о том], кто [именно]*), а затем - в качестве **переходного** (*забывать того, кто*). Попытка объединить при помощи "а также" эти различающиеся случаи применения глагола и создаёт ощущение "бузины с дядькой" (ср. "**забыть о закрытом банке и пин-код**"; не лучше и в обратном порядке). Выправить эту особенность предложения можно двумя способами: а) (канцелярский вариант) поставить двоеточие сразу после "забывать" и пронумеровать по пунктам "предаваемое забвению" (тогда читающему придётся каждый нумерованный пункт индивидуально связать с глаголом) или б) повторить глагол "забывать" после "а также" (это снимет "непереходное последействие" ранее применённого глагола).

Comment: Диссонанс грамматический или стилистический? О втором спорить не хочу сейчас, а первого не вижу. Задал этот вопрос после безуспешных попыток общения на эту тему с другим "ответчиком".

Comment: Мы не ответчики, мы - участники форума.ОТВЕТЧИК,. Тот, кому предъявлен судебный иск (противоп.: истец). О. на суде. Вызов ответчика. Вопрос к ответчику. 2. Разг. Тот, кто несёт ответственность за кого-, что-

Comment: @behemothus Скорее всего, он стилистический, но настолько сильный, что не имеет значения, как классифицировать речевую ошибку (вопрос так не стоял).

Comment: Понял. Нет, для меня вопрос, грамматический или стилистический, принципиален. Я в молодости грамматическими анализаторами баловался, там приходилось разделять строго.

Answer (score 0):

**И всё-таки неправильно**. Нарушен строй сложноподчинённого предложения в части: *забывать,* *...а также того...* Однородные придаточные присоединяются к  слову ЗАБЫВАТЬ, находящемуся в главном предложении, союзным словом КТО, а здесь явное нарушение структуры: соединительный союз *а также* должен присоединять только однородные конструкции, а указательное слово *того* и придаточные предложения не могут быть однородными.

*Зачем минусовать? Давайте разбираться.*

Comment: Тогда на что следует заменить "а также того"?

Comment: Надо соединить два последних придаточных союзом И:  ...всему миру и   кто в своих изысканных...

Comment: Спасибо. А не слишком ли часто будет повторяться союз "и"?

Comment: На мой взгляд, всё нормально.

Comment: *Все придаточные присоединяются к слову ЗАБЫВАТЬ, находящемуся в главном предложении, союзным словом КТО, а здесь явное нарушение структуры.* - а кто сказал, что последнее не может быть присоединено другим способом? "Забыть <что-1>, <что-2>, а также того, кто..." -  в чем здесь ошибка-то?

Comment: *Надо соединить два последних придаточных союзом И* - вот это не стоит делать. Они по смыслу неоднородны. "Забывать что" и "забывать кого". Если их сделать однородными, другой смысл будет.

Comment: Если придаточные задуманы неоднородными, тогда другое дело. Я была уверена, что должны быть однородными. Было бы красиво.

Comment: Ну а как в этом можно быть уверенным, если от автора не спросишь, а фраза построена именно так, как есть, а там явная неоднородность? Понимаете в чем штука, даже самый косноязычный автор не вставит здесь  "а также того"  просто место заполнить, когда и без него можно прекрасно обойтись. Значит, ему нужен был здесь какой-то излом, противопоставление (кого  - чему)...

Comment: Т.е. я вижу здесь осознанную неоднородность, даже если таких слов автор и не знает, такое построение фразы выглядит сознательным.

Comment: Насчет минусов. Не знаю, кто это был, но не обращайте внимания. Я четыре года на ресурсе, тоже начинал с того, что "надо разбираться". К сожалению, приходила очередная волна новичков - и все возвращалась на круги своя. Каждому с каждым разобраться невозможно. И потом есть люди, которые категорически не желают разбираться, начинают права качать. На первый раз я вам компенсирую.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за поддержку).

Answer (score 0):

Кажется, мы стали забывать, **кто** из исторических рэп-фигур в одиночку с пеной у рта проложил дорогу в русскую хип-хоп индустрию, **кто** агрессивным натиском и безудержным напором вырвался из мейнстрима, **кто** стал путеводной звездой и источником вдохновения для сотен тысяч людей по всему миру **и кто**  в своих изысканных, умных и проникновенных треках отчетливо напомнил об эпохе самовыражения.

Всё правильно у Nika. Все придаточные предложения явно **однородны** по содержанию, поэтому нужен **соединительный союз И,** а не присоединительный союз  А ТАКЖЕ. При постановке именно  замыкающего союз И обеспечивается ясное прочтение и понимание предложения.

Грамматически конструкция "стали забывать, кто (1), кто (2), кто (3), а также того, кто (4) **неверна.**

Comment: *Грамматически конструкция "стали забывать, кто (1), кто (2), кто (3), а также того, кто (4) неверна.* - утверждение, построенное исключительно на мнении автора. В грамматике нет таких запретов. .

Comment: Предложение с союзом А ТАКЖЕ должно иметь следующую структуру: "стали забывать того, кто (1), того, кто (2), того, кто (3), а также того, кто (4). В этом случае присоединительный союз А ТАКЖЕ  закрывает ряд указательных слов, а в исходном варианте  этот ряд отсутствует, поэтому союз вместе с указательным словом появляется неизвестно зачем, как черт из табакерки. И еще о грамматике: грамматика предлагает нам разрешенные формы, но при этом не может предусмотреть и запретить все возможные фантазии и нарушения форм, которые могут возникнуть в головах ее пользователей.

Comment: Sergey, ну это только Ваше мнение, ничем и никем не подтвержденное. В сочетании с последней сентенцией насчет фантазий пользователей воспринимается как плоды творчества незабвенного чеховского унтера Пришибеева.  **"Нешто можно дозволять, чтобы народ безобразил? Где это в законе написано, чтоб народу волю давать?"*

Comment: Сочинительные союзы, отнесенные к однородным придаточным,  соединяют или союзные слова, или указательные слова,  но только не союзные слова с указательными словами.  Попробуйте проработать тему "СПП с несколькими придаточными, союзная и бессоюзная связь".

Comment: А здесь неоднородные придаточные. И еще. ***Sergey, вашке постоянные поучения, что кому надо проработать будут отныне встречать то, что Вы называете "негативно окрашенной лексикой".*** Разбираться будете с модераторами. Я вообще меторов не люблю, а уж из числа тех, кто сам плавает...

Comment: Это ОДНОРОДНЫЕ  изъяснительные придаточные: они относятся к одному опорному слову "забывать",  имеют одинаковые союзные слова КТО.

Comment: Это **неоднородные придаточные**, именно потому, что присоединены разным способом и отвечают на разные вопросы.

Comment: Это между собой однородные придаточные могут связываться любыми союзами (соединительными, противительными, присоединительными), а с главным предложением они соединены с помощью одинаковых союзных слов. И отвечают на один вопрос: забывают (кого?).

Comment: Я не собираюсь обсуждать *с Вами), как моггут быть связаны меэду собой придаточные. Ваше утверждение строится на неверном предположении, что придаточные, относящиеся к одному слову, обязательно однородны. Если вы объясните, откуда такое, обсуждение будет иметь смысл. Иначе, простите, говорить тут не о чем.

Comment: Валгина, Розенталь: Однородными являются одноименные (одинаковые по семантике) придаточные, относящиеся к одному и тому же слову главной части предложения или ко всей главной части в целом. http://sci.house/yazyik-russkiy/sovremennyiy-russkiy-yazyik-uchebnik-pod.html

Comment: А здесь **разная** семантика. Определение, кстати, не самое удачное. Из него не следует, какие придаточные называются неоднородными. *"Неоднородными являются придаточные, разные по значению (при одинаковой отнесенности к главной части), а также одинаковые по значению, но отнесенные к разным словам главной части.:"* - та же Валгина. http://yanko.lib.ru/books/language/ru/yanko.valgina_2003_416p_rasp_sl.htm.

Comment: У наших придаточных одинаковое значение: они ИЗЪЯСНИТЕЛЬНЫЕ.

Comment: А это тип, а не значение придаточных. Да и не имеет это никакого значения. Они у нас на разные вопросы отвечают.

Comment: На один, кажется: стали забывать (кого?).

Comment: Это вы стали забывать. Я сразу сказал, что это **разные** по смыслу вопросы. Я просто допускаю различное построение модели грамматик, но оно должно быть непротиворечивое. А у вас разных кусков нахватано из разных подходов.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36161/discussion-between-behemothus-and-sergey).

Comment: Я-то при чем,  это фраза из текста: "Кажется, мы стали забывать (о чем? о каких фактах?). Или: кого, о ком? Вопросы можно разные задать, но для всех придаточных выбранный вопрос будет ОБЩИМ.  Впрочем, Вы уже задали новую тему, надеюсь, что получите удовлетворяющий Вас ответ.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, ошибки есть. Я бы написал так:

"Кажется, мы стали забывать, какие из исторических рэп-фигур в одиночку, с пеной у рта, проложили себе дорогу на площадку русской хип-хоп-индустрии. Тех, кто агрессивным натиском и безудержным напором вырвался из мейнстрима, кто стал путеводной звездой и источником вдохновения для сотен тысяч людей по всему миру, тех, кто в своих изысканных, умных и проникновенных треках отчетливо напомнил нам об эпохе самовыражения".

P.S. Хорошо хоть, что пришли к решению остановиться в словарях на варианте "рэп". Прежде вообще фигурировало "реп". ))

Answer (score -1):

Да такое вполне возможно, грамматических ошибок нет. 
Вопрос, как я понимаю возник в связи с наличием двух типов подчиненных предложений "[забывать], кто" и "[забывать] того, кто", управляеых одним словом "забывать". Но грамматика не накладывает ограничений на такие конструкции, вполне можно сказать "забыть Петю, Машу, а так же того, кто побил Борю". не знаю, насколько верен выбор стилистически, но грамматика тут корректная.

//==================

Сомневающимся в грамматической правильности конструкции.

Выходила, песню заводила
Про степного сизого орла,
Про того, которого любила,
Про того, чьи письма берегла.
(С)

Чем здесь лучше? Тоже перечисление в ряд, только подцеплено не к глаголу, а к песне, но зато тремя разными способами: *"про кого", "про того, кто", "про того, чьи"*.

Или объясняйте, чем этот вариант правильнее рассматриваемого, или соглашайтесь.

Comment: Спасибо. В таком случае следует убрать "того"?

Comment: Нет, я же сказал, что все нормально. Не уверен, что будет лучше, если убрать. Как бы хуже не стало.